# Need A 2-Way Size Reduction Hashing Algorithm

Tags: java, math, networking, hash

We have 32-bit global id strings used to identify objects in our system and mobile id strings that uniquely identify our cell phone clients. Currently the mobile id is a cell phone number, but it could potentially be generated to be anything.

In order to save network traffic, it would be useful for us to combine these two strings into another smaller string, which we call the local id, and transfer that id to the phone instead of the global id. When the phone transfers the local id back to us we convert the local id back to a global id and process it. The local id must be unique to the phone, but not globally unique. The mobile id is already shared between the client and the server, so there is no need to transmit it.

Our first thought is to have an array of gigantic tables on the server, each one mapping global id to local id for a given mobile id. However, if there is a simple algorithm that exists such that we can do

```
algorithm(mobileid, globalid) = localid     -----> server sends localid to client

client sends localid back to server

algorithm(mobileid, localid) = globalid
```

Is this even possible? If so whats the best way to start?
Please and thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't the client just use the global id?

Comment: Because the whole point of this is to save network traffic by having the localid be smaller than the globalid.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle quickly demonstrates that there is no such algorithm in the general case.  Is some kind of dynamic lookup table on the server really a problem?

Comment: Not enough information.  How many "objects in our system" are there, and how do they relate to your "cell phone clients"? Is there anything special about the 32-bit "string", and is it a string in the sense of a string of characters?  You can convert two values to one value, and quite possibly make the one value shorter than the concatenation of the two original values, depending on what the original values are - eg if they're both decimal number strings, you can shorten them several ways.  But in order to help you with a "simple algorithm" we have to know more about what you're starting with.

Comment: No, there is no simple (or otherwise) algorithm that will reversibly compress all 32-bit numbers, obviously. Are there any constraints or internal structure in the global ids that limit the possible values to less than 2^32?

Comment: The mobile id is already shared between the client and the server, so there is no need to transmit it.

There is nothing special about the 32-bit string, other than the fact that it uniquely identifies the objects in our system. They do not in any way relate to the individual cell phone clients, they are globally unique.

The amount of objects in our system is very large.

Answer (score 0):

You need a local id such:

- You can decode Global Id from it
- You can decode Mobile Id from it

So the trivial way is the lookup table, but you already said you don't want that.

What you need is not a hasing algorithm but a compression algorithm, since you want to extract the same data again. Since you don't have much data (32 bits + phone number), i don't think that a traditional compression algorithm will work for you.

The thing that cought my attention is when you say 32-bit **strings**, If you have a string representation of a 32-bit number you need 10 chars (max unsigned int = 4294967295), but you actually only need 4 bytes. Same with the phone number.
If because of your protocol you need the number to be stored as an ascii string, you could use base64 encoding.

Comment: The 32-bit global id strings are already encoded in base 64. I don't need the mobile id encoded in the local id, as it is already shared between the client and the server. After more thinking about the problem I don't think this is solvable without a lookup table.

Comment: I agree with you. I know you don't need encoding, I was suggesting it to get a smaller string (smaller than decimal string), but you are already doing that.

Comment: @Ring Encoding 32-bit values into Base64 will only make them longer, so I don't know why you are doing that. Are they really 32 bits, or do you perhaps mean 32 bytes? if the former, surely there can't be much saving in truncating 32 bits?